# How to avoid change in border's width when two borders are overlapping?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make two borders overlapping without changing width of an intersected border? I know that I can just make `border-top: none;` for the bottom `div`, but I'm looking for another solution is it possible.

Thank you.

**UPDATE** I prefer global solution is it possible at all

This is example:

```css
.box{
    border: solid thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Test></div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding a negative margin, you may want to target the div individually with an id or something though (or a new class if you wanted it more global).

```css
.box{
    border: solid thin;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Test></div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
```

As mentioned in comments, you should use px (instead of "thin") especially if you have a border size over 1px (and even if you don't for good practice), because if you change border size, you have to change the negative margin accordingly.

Comment: **Note:** This solution will [display poorly if the border is translucent](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/65msad68/) as the borders are not actually collapsed and will overlap, as well this will display poorly if [the border width is any larger than its current size](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/65msad68/1/) as the elements are being moved upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an alternative solution since you asked for it.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    border: solid thin;
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="box">Test</div>
    <div class="box">Test1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this constitutes as "another way," but here's a way to do it without negative margins.

```css
.outer-box {
  border: solid thin;
}
.box:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: solid thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="box">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Test 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` selector it will check if `.box` has a next sibling and remove `border` from it

```css
.box {
  border: solid thin;
}
.box + .box {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Test></div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
<div class="box">Test1</div>
```